# PHP get line number from logging event

Tags: php, logging, line-numbers, magic-constants

Ok I have another question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213423/php-how-could-i-make-this-class-better-suggestions-feedback-welcome) for my Logging Class but I wanted to be able to add the line number of the calling script to the log file entry.

I have seen **[**Line**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)** but this gives me the line number of the line where this is at.

Example:

a.php

```
$log = new Logger();
$log->debug('hello'); // Say this is line #20
```

Now in my Logger.php class in the debug() I use the **[**Line**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)** Magic Constant on for example line #300. When I run the script I would like the log entry to read 'on line 20' but it read 'on line 300'. Besides passing the line number to the function is there any other way I could do this?

Example debug class function

```
public function debug($message) {
        if(DEBUG) {
            $this->calling_script = $this->getScriptBaseName();
            $this->log_file = LOG_FILE_DIRECTORY."/".$this->calling_script.".log";
            $this->fh = fopen($this->log_file, 'a') or die("Can't open log file: ".$this->log_file);
                
            if($this->first_run) {
                $this->log_entry = "\n[" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime()) . "][debug][line:".__LINE__."]:\t".$message."\n";
            } else {
                $this->log_entry = "[" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime()) . "][debug][line:".__LINE__."]:\t".$message."\n";
            }       
            fwrite($this->fh, $this->log_entry);
            fclose($this->fh);
            
            $this->first_run = false;
        }       
    }
```

EDIT: debug_backtrace() works great!!! Working below

```
public function debug($message) {
        if(DEBUG) {
            $debug_arr = debug_backtrace();
            $this->calling_script = $this->getScriptBaseName();
            $this->log_file = LOG_FILE_DIRECTORY."/".$this->calling_script.".log";
            $this->fh = fopen($this->log_file, 'a') or die("Can't open log file: ".$this->log_file);
                
            if($this->first_run) {
                $this->log_entry = "\n[" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime()) . "][debug]:\t".$message." [line:".$debug_arr[0]['line']."]\n";
            } else {
                $this->log_entry = "[" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime()) . "][debug]:\t".$message." [line:".$debug_arr[0]['line']."]\n";
            }       
            fwrite($this->fh, $this->log_entry);
            fclose($this->fh);
            
            $this->first_run = false;
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to use [`debug_backtrace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) for this or else always pass the line (with `__LINE__`) to the function.

Comment: +1 Note that `debug_backtrace` is slooow, so it should really be used only in debugging mode.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)? I'm not sure of its overhead though.